# How to use KivyMD fonts in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have downloaded the **KivyMD** (Kivy Material Design) because of the basic looking natural design of **Kivy**.

However, I am unsure of how to use everything that comes with it?

I've tried to do the normal import of a font name from **KivyMD**, and the font didn't run

```
    Label:
        text: 'Logged in!'
        font_size: 100
        font_name: 'Material_Design_Iconic_Font'
```

Comment: The `font_name` (misleading name) is actually the name of the file containing the font. The font file is found using the `resource_find()` method, unless you provide an absolute path. So, you can either provide the path to desired font, or you can add the directory that holds it to the resource path.

Comment: Yea I figured it out @JohnAnderson it wasn't in the right path. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[KivyMD](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD)**'s widget *MDLabel* to use fonts and colors that are setted by theme (*ThemeManager*), or *MDIcon* to use Material icons.

But if you really want to use Kivy's *Label* widget, you can write:

```yaml
#:import md_icons kivymd.icon_definitions.md_icons

BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: f"[color=#000000][font=Roboto]Logged[/font] [font=RobotoMedium]in![/font] [font=Icons]{md_icons['login']}[/font][/color]"
        markup: True
        font_size: 100
```

Full code:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

root_kv = """
#:import md_icons kivymd.icon_definitions.md_icons

BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: f"[color=#000000][font=Roboto]Logged[/font] [font=RobotoMedium]in![/font] [font=Icons]{md_icons['login']}[/font][/color]"
        markup: True
        font_size: 100
"""


class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(root_kv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

fonts style example:

```
KV = '''
Screen:
MDLabel:
text: "JetBrainsMono"
halign: "center"
font_style: "JetBrainsMono"
'''

from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.font_definitions import theme_font_styles
class MainApp(MDApp):
def build(self):
LabelBase.register(
name="JetBrainsMono",
fn_regular="JetBrainsMono-Regular.ttf")
theme_font_styles.append('JetBrainsMono')
self.theme_cls.font_styles["JetBrainsMono"] = [
"JetBrainsMono",
16,
False,
0.15,
]
return Builder.load_string(KV)
MainApp().run()
```

[ref](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/kivymd/latest/kivymd.pdf)

Comment: if you have more questions I put the link to the documentation.